# Extract text from character vector using regex

Tags: r, regex, vector, character

I have this character vector:

```
>a
[[1]]
    [1] "\nCEJAMA - COOPERATIVA DE ELETRICIDADE JACINTO MACHADO\n2.878,95\n1.457.218,40\n1.860.357,63\n5.220,00\n506,16\n646,19\nCELESC-DIS - CELESC DISTRIBUIÇÃO
S.A**\n1.324.445,20\n611.036.730,94\n821.738.507,45\n3.064.084,00\n461,35\n620,44\n**CELG-D - CELG
DISTRIBUIÇÃO S.A.\n893.479,43\n412.181.508,00\n637.954.505,58\n3.120.340,00\n461,32\n714,01\nCELPE - COMPANHIA ENERGÉTICA DE PERNAMBUCO\n895.712,59\n431.113.973,93\n576.900.942,45\n3.761.190,00\n481,31\n644,07\nCEMAR - COMPANHIA
ENERGÉTICA DO MARANHÃO\n481.531,73\n267.383.865,68\n348.554.651,61\n2.564.221,00\n555,28\n723,85"
```

I would like to extract, using regex, everything between "CELESC-DIS - CELESC DISTRIBUIÇÃO S.A and CELG-D" and insert into a dataframe.

I tried `str_extract_all(a,'(CELESC-DIS - CELESC DISTRIBUIÇÃO S.A)(.*?)(CELG-D)')` but it doesn´t work.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to be a `list`, so either do `unlist(a)` or `a[[1]]`

Comment: Please add the output you get from the code

Comment: Not sure if it is applicable here, but I think you also have to make the dot match a newline if it spans multiple lines https://regex101.com/r/rMc4IA/1